# Multiplication method does not work

Tags: java

I'm new to programming and was going through this code.

It's supposed to **multiply** the lowest number by the highest and **display** the **result** but the result is **always incorrect**.

For example, if I enter the **lowest** integer as `1` and the **highest** integer as `10`, the output is `3628800` instead of `10` (`1 * 10`).

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    int highest, lowest;
    int product = 1;
    BufferedReader kb = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    // Read user input
    System.out.println("Enter the lowest integer: ");
    lowest = Integer.parseInt(kb.readLine());
    System.out.println("Enter the highest integer: ");
    highest = Integer.parseInt(kb.readLine());

    // Multiply
    for (int count = highest ; count >= lowest ; count--) {
        product = product * count;
    }

    System.out.println("The product is: " + product);
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example input, the expected and the current output? Where do you think the problem is? Did you check if your variables are what you think they are? For example using simple small print statements like `System.out.println(variableXY);`. Please take a look at [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @Zabuza For example, if i enter the lowest integer as 1 and the highest integer as 10, the output is 3628800

Comment: You are going to need to learn how to do this yourself, and now is a good time to start.  https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Yeah, since you multiple it in a `for-loop` (so you repeatedly multiply). What did you expect as output, `1 * 10 = 10`?.

Comment: @Zabuza Yes. i expected the output as a 10. I just need to know what's wrong with the code and why I'm getting a high number. I know it has something to do with the loop, but i'm not exactly sure what part of it.

Comment: @Zabuza. Ohhhh. That makes sense. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. Just add a `System.out.println(product);` and `System.out.println(count);` inside the `for-loop` and you will notice such stuff by yourself next time. Pen and paper might also help to see whether such a simple algorithm works, using a small example like `2` and `3`.

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation

The problem is your loop, let's take a look at it:

```
int product = 1;
for (int count = highest ; count >= lowest ; count--) {
    product = product * count;
}
```

Assume `highest = 10` and `lowest = 7`.

Then your counter starts with `10` and you compute

```
product = 1 * 10 = 10
```

After that the loop continues by decreasing the counter `count--`, it is now `9` and you multiply the last result by that, yielding

```
product = 10 * 9 = 90
```

This repeats, the counter is `8` in the next iteration, yielding

```
product = 90 * 8 = 720
```

And in the last iteration it is `7`, yielding the final result

```
product = 720 * 7 = 5040
```

The loop now ends since in the next iteration `count` would be `6` but your condition is

```
count >= lowest
    6 >= 7      // false, aborting
```

---

### Solution

I'm not that sure why you wrote such a complicated code, nonetheless here are two variants

```
// Easiest and most efficient
int product = highest * lowest;

// Repeatedly adding highest lowest-times
int product = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < lowest; i++) {
    product += highest;
}
```

For the second variant take a look at the example from above (`highest = 10`, `lowest = 7`):

```
  10 * 7 = 70
= 10 + 10 + 10 + 10 + 10 + 10 + 10 // Adding 10 7-times
```

Note that multiplication is **commutative**, the order doesn't matter:

```
  highest * lowest
=  lowest * highest
```

So there is **no need for differentiating** `highest` from `lowest`.